# How to update SharePoint List item via infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, updatelistitems

I have created an Infopath form with 2 views.

I first view, user enter the details and submit the form that generate a unique ID basis on List Item ID.

in second view there are some fields for Manager to add comment and other details .

Now the issue I am facing is that after adding his/her data, when manager click on submit button, It create a new Item in list instead of updating the current item.

> In submit option I am using a Data connection with following formula
>   to create form/Item name: `concat("someText",(max(ID)+1))`

I am unable to find the solution on how to update the Item via Infopath button.

I am using sharePoint online.

Comment: how did you design your form? please provide your steps to reproduce this issue containing rules.

Comment: please check the edit part...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Submit button, I suggest you use "Save" button to submit the change:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some InfoPath fields have a way to submit data back to SharePoint via a browser connection.
On the properties of the object, example Text Box Properties, go to the Browser Form tab.
In the Postback settings, choose 'Always'. Then this control will send data back to the server once the value changes.

I believe this will only occur if the SharePoint item has been created i.e. not before submit.

I know no easy way to do this by a button.

Cheerio!